# How to enter vertical values in Tables in HTML via AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

For the starters, I would like to have something like this,

```
Array 1     Array 2     Array 3     Array 4
Arr1val1    Arr2val1    Arr3val1    Arr4val1
Arr1val2    Arr2val2    Arr3val2    Arr4val2
Arr1val3                Arr3val3    Arr4val3
Arr1val4                            Arr4val4
                                    Arr4val5
```

I have already solved the issue in the crudest way possible,a solution that won't scale to other data types and if number of variable increase to lets say 10 columns it will fail in the most glorious way which makes me cringe and ask for suggestions of improvement. 
My naive approach is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxmjpkp/2/) in a fiddle.
As the code is simple I would like to explain what I did.
Step 1 : Calculate the highest number of elements in all arrays and the array from which it is coming.
Step 2 : Make the number of elements in all array same as the number of elements in the highest number of element possible by filling in blanks.
Step 3 : Iterate over one in the HTML and print all.

**Would like to know what can be done to make this solution better and more scalable?**

Comment: why don't you use another `ng-repeat` in your `ng-repeat`?

Comment: How do u suggest it ? because I don't think that is case required here

Comment: @CozyAzure could you give some code example to prove your point?

Comment: sorry, totally misunderstood the question. I was thinking why don't you just iterate over a 2-d array. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of finding max length of arrays, push all the values to the specific array.
2. Draw a table inside the td. So here the data are drawn vertically.

> Using this scenario, you can add any number of data to any array, since
>   this is generating vertically.

Please see the working code
[https://jsfiddle.net/yaxmjpkp/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/yaxmjpkp/6/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  //Test case 1
  $scope.arr1 = ["Arr1val1", "Arr1val2", "Arr1val3", "Arr1val4"];
  $scope.arr2 = ["Arr2val1", "Arr2val2"];
  $scope.arr3 = ["Arr3val1", "Arr3val2", "Arr3val3"];
  $scope.arr4 = ["Arr4val1", "Arr4val2", "Arr4val3", "Arr4val4", "Arr4val5","Arrayval6"];

  $scope.tableValues=[];
  
  $scope.tableValues.push($scope.arr1);
  $scope.tableValues.push($scope.arr2);
  $scope.tableValues.push($scope.arr3);
  $scope.tableValues.push($scope.arr4);
  debugger
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <td>
          Header 1
        </td>
        <td>
          Header 2
        </td>
        <td>
          Header 3
        </td>
        <td>
          Header 4
        </td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td ng-repeat="val in tableValues" valign = "top">
            <table>
               <tr ng-repeat="val2 in val">
                 <td>{{val2}}</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't need to do the first two steps. As javascript is loosely typed language and so is angular (although its not a language but its built over JS). So when you access some value like

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in arr1 track by $index">
      <td>{{arr1[$index]}}</td>
      <td>{{arr2[$index]}}</td>
      <td>{{arr3[$index]}}</td>
      <td>{{arr4[$index]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Angular won't find any element on that index (Because of the unequal size of that array). So you won't have any issue regarding the access of the value on that particular index. And an empty `<td>` will be added in that place.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with you. That I need to delete the first two steps. I think I need the first step. Here is the [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/y2mamh4n/). I need to know what is the highest element array. As you can see I am missing out on one values from array4 . But then thanks this is certainly better than mine... Upvote to you. You can see @Kindzoku's answer for the first step. He has a good solution for the first step.

Comment: I am talking about skipping step 1 and step 2 and just using same html on the array like you were using in the jsfiddle given in question. It will have the same effect as it is now. So you won't have to use first 2 steps. I have verified it on my end as well

Comment: Could you modify the fiddle in my comment above? It is basically a solution to what you are saying but I feel there is something wrong with your approach. Step 1 finding the array with the highest number of elements. Which is important. Just used arr2 instead of arr1 and see the result.

Comment: Yes you are right. In that case the array are only showing 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, you can store array elements in associative array and you can check max length in a more generic way.

```
  $scope.arrs = {
    arr1: ["Arr1val1", "Arr1val2", "Arr1val3", "Arr1val4"],
    arr2: ["Arr2val1", "Arr2val2"],
    arr3: ["Arr3val1", "Arr3val2", "Arr3val3"],
    arr4: ["Arr4val1", "Arr4val2", "Arr4val3", "Arr4val4", "Arr4val5"]
  };

  var maxLength = 0;
  for(var arrKey in $scope.arrs){
    maxLength = Math.max($scope.arrs[arrKey].length, maxLength);
  });
```

Here is complete solution: https://plnkr.co/edit/p6EcXeiRKHY2wQA3xCi4?p=preview

Comment: I think If I combine your answer with Umair Farooq's answer it will be the best answer. You have the excellent first step. And he figured out the last. And we don't need the second step. Upvote to you for this approach.

Comment: How do I get which array has the maximum elements? I need that for the frontend.